# How to reference classes from two different targets in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have two different targets in my app, and I want to display a certain view controller upon launch depending on the target. Right now my code looks like this:

```
if target1:
   window?.rootViewController = ViewController1()
else:
   window?.rootViewController = ViewController2()
```

However, there is an issue here as Xcode is saying that it can't recognize class `ViewController2`. `AppDelegate.swift` is a member of both targets, `ViewController1` is a member of target 1, and `ViewController2` is a member of target 2. Whenever I set ViewController2 as a member of target 2, this error goes away, but the same error pops up in `ViewController2.swift` whenever I reference another file that is only a member of target 2.

Comment: Honestly it is probably easier to just duplicate your appdelegate

Comment: How do I make sure that a particular target launches a particular appdelegate?

Comment: Each target would have its own app delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using navigation controller and use view controller identifier to set my target controller. 
try this out may this will help you

```
 if target1{
 let window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let navigate = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "ViewController") as! ViewController
  navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigate)
  window?.rootViewController = navController
  navigate.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}else{
   let window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let navigate = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
   "ViewController") as! ViewController
   navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigate)
   window?.rootViewController = navController
   navigate.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You should add both ViewController1 and ViewController2 to both target because xcode can only reach the files that selected in target while compiling the code. So according to selected target, xcode does not recognize the other viewController if you do not add it either.

Comment: well if you are target to navigation controller and use class identifier then it is easy to set as many controllers in app delegate hope you know about navigation controller.

Comment: By that logic every file in the entire project needs to be a part of both projects which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Kevin2566 that is what you will need to do, which is why I say it is probably simpler to have two app delegates

Comment: @VipinPareek yes i know about navigation controller and yes you have to add each view controller separately in navigation controller to use this in your selected target.

Comment: @gokhankilic i think that's the question sorry if i'm out of track